# Asymptotic Expansion at $x=0$ and at $x=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I differentiate the asymptotic expansions at $x=0$ and at $x=\infty$.

I see that for asymptotic expansions near $x=0$, I have something like $f(x)=\ldots+O(x^4)$ - the exponent in the remainder term has a positive power.

Whereas for asymptotic expansions near x=infinity, I have something like $f(x)=\ldots+O(x^{-4})$ - the exponent in the remainder term has a negative power.

Is this one of the ways or the only way to distinguish between the $x=0$ case and the $x=\infty$ case?

Are there different methods to computing the expansions for both of these cases, or are they the same ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use MathJax formatting.